# how can I update multiple record list from a form in Django 1.9

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a shipment_details form where have some information about shipment and all item in that order of the shipments. There is two model information one Shipment another is Items  model. I want to update all Marco Item Shipped value using the checkbox( see the form view pics). 
here is my form view
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WA6gt.jpg
Here is my forms.py where I linked up checkbox to Items is_shipped field and this value show in the view using `{{form_status.as_p}}`.
**forms.py**

```
class ShipmentStatus(forms.CheckboxInput):
    input_type = 'checkbox'

class ShipmentStatusForm((forms.ModelForm)):
    class Meta:
        model = Items
        fields = ['is_shipped']
        widgets = {
            'is_shipped': ShipmentStatus(),
        }
```

Here is my view model
**shipment_detail.html**

```
{% extends "_dashboardlayout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2 class="page-header">Shipment Details</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form method="POST" action="">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item No</th>
                        <th>SKU</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Marco Item</th>
                        <th>Marco Item Shipped</th>
                    </tr>
                    {% for item in items_queryset %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ item.item_no }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.sku }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.requested_quantity }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.is_send }}</td>
                        <td>{{ form_status.as_p }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </table>
                <input type="submit" value="Save">
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is my control py file

```
def shipment_detail(request, order_id=None):
    order_queryset = Order.objects.get(order_id=order_id)
    customer_queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    address_queryset = Address.objects.all()
    items_queryset = Items.objects.filter(order_id=order_id).order_by('item_no')
    shipment_queryset = Shipment.objects.filter(order_id=order_id)
    # if there is no shipment data then generate shipment details for the Order
    if not shipment_queryset:
        form = ShipmentForm(request.POST or None)
        form_status = ShipmentStatusForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.order_id = order_queryset
            order_queryset.save()
            instance.save()

        # save item status
        if form_status.is_valid():
            instance = form_status.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()

        context = {
            "form": form,
            "form_status": form_status,
            "order_queryset": order_queryset,
            "customer_queryset": customer_queryset,
            "address_queryset": address_queryset,
            "items_queryset": items_queryset,
        }
        return render(request, "shipment_detail.html", context)
    # if there is already data then updated the shipment details for the Order
    else:
        instance = get_object_or_404(Shipment, order_id=order_id)
        form = ShipmentForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.order_id = order_queryset
            # updated order is_shipped field according to ship_status
            if instance.status == True:
                order_queryset.is_shipped = True

            if instance.status == False:
                order_queryset.is_shipped = False

            # updated order is_completed field according to shipment is_complete field
            if instance.is_complete == True:
                order_queryset.is_completed = True

            if instance.is_complete == False:
                order_queryset.is_completed = False

            order_queryset.save()

            instance.save()

        print "form  status"

        # updated item is_shipped field
        instance_status = get_list_or_404(Items, order_id=order_id)

        for instance in instance_status:
            form_status = ShipmentStatusForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
            if form_status.is_valid():
                instance = form_status.save(commit=False)
                instance.save()

        context = {
            "form": form,
            "instance": instance,
            "form_status": form_status,
            "order_queryset": order_queryset,
            "customer_queryset": customer_queryset,
            "address_queryset": address_queryset,
            "items_queryset": items_queryset,
        }
        return render(request, "shipment_detail.html", context)
```

Here problem is when click all the Marco Item Shipped true or false its save value properly but if I click one false another true then it doesn't save value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is use pk of an object as value of check box

```
<input type="checkbox" value='{{item.id}}' 
                         name='for_action' id='for_action' >
```

, You can get list of these pk in your views using `request.POST.getlist('for_action')`

*Here You Go!!*

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2 class="page-header">Shipment Details</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th>Item No</th>
                    <th>SKU</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Marco Item</th>
                    <th>Marco Item Shipped</th>
                </tr>
                {% for item in items_queryset %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ item.item_no }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.sku }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.requested_quantity }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.is_send }}</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" value='{{item.id}}' 
                     name='for_action' id='for_action' ></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Save">
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

{% endblock %}

views.py

```
def shipment_detail(request, order_id=None):
        #########

        # save item status
        list_of_id_for_action = request.POST.getlist('for_action')
        list_of_obj = Items.objects.filter(pk__in=list_of_id_for_action)
        list_of_obj.update(is_shipped=True)

        ######


        context = {
            "form": form,
            "instance": instance,
            "form_status": form_status,
            "order_queryset": order_queryset,
            "customer_queryset": customer_queryset,
            "address_queryset": address_queryset,
            "items_queryset": items_queryset,
        }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Do you need to call `form.is_valid()` here?

Comment: If you are using forms and need to validate the data , yes you can.